# C - Automatically calling a function if module is included

Tags: c

I have created a module with a struct that has a custom printf handler. is there a way to automatically call `register_printf_function ('W', print_widget, print_widget_arginfo);` if the module is included, like `include "widget.h"`, on other C program?

Comment: Nothing portable.  Look into your compiler's documentation.

Comment: Generally you simply `include "widget.h"` and if the compiler cannot load the header, the compilation will fail at that point, otherwise you can register your custom printf function..

Comment: Or using a conditional, based on the header guard of `widget.h` (e.g. `#ifdef WIDGET_H_PRESENT`)